# TreeRouteStack with segments in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, url-routing

I'm having a bit of trouble with making a segment child route for a segment route in Zend Framework 2. I've tried to get it from the docs, but it's a bit confusing to me. Wondered it anyone could help me.

This is basically the route I want to define:

```
root/monitor/customer/12424/job/1243
```

Where 12424 is the customer ID and 1243 is the job ID. The job part could be a different action, too.

Below is what I've tried to do with routing. I've tried several unsuccessful approaches, but this is just the one I have currently. Everything up until job works.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'monitor' => array(
            'type'      =>  'segment',
            'options'   => array(
                'route' => '/monitor[/][:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Monitor\Controller\Monitor',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'customer' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/customer/:id[/][/:action/:jobid]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'customer'
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ),          
        ),
    ),
),
```

I am getting the following 404 error:

```
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
```

Comment: Any specicfic reason on using this as it is    'route' => '/customer/:id[/][/:action/:jobid]', from looks its something like you are getting action on the basis of id

Answer (score 0):

You should try to refactor it to something like this, by separating the static part and putting the rest in child_routes :

```
        'monitor' => array(
            'type'      =>  'literal',
            'options'   => array(
                'route' => '/monitor',
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'something' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '[/:action][/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Monitor\Controller\Monitor',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'customer' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/customer/:id[/:action/:jobid]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'customer'
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```